# Testing abstract classes in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, nosetests, python-unittest

Consider the following scenario.

```
import six
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class ThisIsAnAbstractClass(six.with_metaclass(ABCMeta)):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self,parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter

    def do_something():
        """do something"""
```

There is a class extended form ABCMeta (an abstract class) with an abstract method in it. This class cannot be initialized because of that abstract **init**() method. Is there a way to test this class? (at least using any testing framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a subclass of the abstract class, then test the subclass.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class ThisIsAnAbstractClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta # <--

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        self.parameter = parameter

    def do_something():
        """do something"""

class ConcreteClass(ThisIsAnAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self, parameter):
        super(ConcreteClass, self).__init__(parameter)

try:
    ThisIsAnAbstractClass('test')
    assert False, 'Abstract class instance created!'
except TypeError:
    pass

assert ConcreteClass('test').parameter == 'test'
```

NOTE: You should use [`abc.ABCMeta`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) as a metaclass.

Comment: Forgot that metaclass.Edited. I thought wanted test the abstract class it self. Seems like there's no way other than creating a sub class of that.