# How to use pytest on an abstract class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, abstract-class

I have one abstract class

```
class Model:
    model_data: ModelData = None

    def write(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("write() must be implemented by {}".format(type(self).__name__))

    def read(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("read() must be implemented by {}".format(type(self).__name__))
```

I wonder how should I write the unit test using pytest for the read and write methods within this abstract class.

Comment: What is the goal of your test? If the goal is to check that subclasses that don't implement `read`/`write` will raise an error, then you can subclass in your test, call `read`/`write` and assert that an exception was raised.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing abstract classes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549116/testing-abstract-classes-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Testing an abstract base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757299/python-testing-an-abstract-base-class)